# Вывести сообщение в область уведомлений

Tags: c++, winapi

пишу на win32api c++. Нужно вывести сообщение в область уведомления. Думал что notifyicon как то к этому причастен, но это вроде не то. и не могу найти простого примера как вывести сообщение. чтобы справа внизу появилось уведомление. например надпись. ну нужна тема и текст вывести. можно пожалуйста пример.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806602/notify-icon-click-win32-api-in-c
Не оно?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov не пойму. вроде не оно.

Comment: Не это? https://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread1526012.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <ShObjIdl.h>

CoInitialize(NULL);
//...
IUserNotification *un = NULL;
if (CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UserNotification, 0, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IUserNotification, (void**)&un) == S_OK)
{
    un->SetBalloonInfo(L"Заголовок", L"Текст сообщения", NIIF_INFO);
    un->Show(NULL, 0); 
    un->Release();
} 
//...
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: ух ты. спасибо. я щас не могу проверить, но поверю.